# If statement 3 conditions Bash

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I want to do an if statement with three conditions that have to be satisfied at the same time. I am using Ubuntu Bash for Windows and the values $c1, $c2 and $c3 are non-integer (decimal negative numbers).

```
if [ (( $(echo "$c1 < 0" | bc -l) )) ]  && [ (( $(echo "$c2 < 0" | bc -l) )) ] && [ (( $(echo "$c3 < 0" | bc -l) )) ];
    then
      >&2 echo -e "   ++ Constraints OK"

else
      >&2 echo -e "   ++ Constraints WRONG"

fi
```

However, I get the following syntax error in the if line: `` syntax error near unexpected token `(' ``

If I just put one condition:

```
if (( $(echo "$c1 < 0" | bc -l) ));
```

it works, but when I add the three of them as AND (`&&`), I get the error. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The problem is `[ ((`. Why do you have a `[` there?

Comment: Toss this beast into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/). It will identify every issue for you. That being said, you can lose the `[` and `]` since you don't need to use the `[`  command as your `bc` output will return a true/false

Comment: Hi, I saw it in a thread but actually, the square brackets are not needed and by removing them, it worked! Thanks and sorry for taking your time!

Comment: So the correct code will be:

if (( $(echo "$cons_low_area < 0" | bc -l) )) && (( $(echo "$cons_up_r_y < 0" | bc -l) )) && (( $(echo "$cons_up_r_x < 0" | bc -l) ));
then
  >&2 echo -e "   ++ Constraints OK"

else
  >&2 echo -e "   ++ Constraint WRONG"

fi

Comment: You just want to know if floating-point values are negative? `[[ $c1 = -* ]]` is much more efficient than `(( $(bc -l <<<"$c1 < 0") ))` (which itself is more efficient than `(( $(echo "$c1 < 0" | bc -l) ))`, since the temporary file created by a heredoc or herestring is cheaper than the FIFO and subprocess created by pipeline setup). Any time you use `$( ... )` it's several milliseconds of overhead; same for a pipeline.

Comment: On a different point, `echo -e` is best avoided -- bash literally breaks black-letter POSIX specification by having it do anything other than print `-e` on output by default (and it has a mode where it *doesn't* break that spec, so `echo -e` prints `-e`... which you probably don't want). See POSIX spec @ http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, particularly the APPLICATION USAGE section suggesting `printf '%b\n' "$foo"` for the use cases where `echo -e "$foo"` might be what one otherwise reaches for.

Comment: @KeithThompson, where did I say anything that contradicts your comment (or imply anything that your comment contradicts)? I didn't lean on that point only because prior comments had already succesfully made it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Oops, I meant to reply to ChristinaHP, not to you. I'll delete my comment and post a new one.

Comment: @CristinaHP: The `[` and `]` are not merely not needed, they're wrong. Many, perhaps most, conditions in shell scripts use `[` and `]`, so it's easy to assume that they're part of the syntax of if. In fact `[` is a command, and `]` is its final argument.

Answer (score 1):

Considerably more efficient (assuming you know your values are numbers, and only need to check whether they're all negative) would be:

```
if [[ $c1 = -* ]] && [[ $c2 = -* ]] && [[ $c3 = -* ]]; then
      >&2 echo "   ++ Constraints OK"
else
      >&2 echo "   ++ Constraints WRONG"
fi
```

---

If you want to be more specific about the permissible formats (f/e, allowing leading spaces), a regex is another option, which similarly can be implemented more efficiently than spawning a series of subshells invoking `bc`:

```
nnum_re='^[[:space:]]*-([[:digit:]]*[.][[:digit:]]+|[[:digit:]]+)$'
if [[ $c1 =~ $nnum_re ]] && [[ $c2 =~ $nnum_re ]] && [[ $c3 =~ $nnum_re ]]; then
      >&2 echo "   ++ Constraints OK"
else
      >&2 echo "   ++ Constraints WRONG"
fi
```

Comment: Is `[[ $c1 = -* ]] && [[ $c2 = -* ]]` faster then `[[ $c1 = -* && $c2 = -* ]]` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk, no difference. The reason to use the former is that it's a practice that's portable over to `[ ]` while avoiding parts of the POSIX `test` standard that are marked obsolescent (see the `OB` markers in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), so whereas I might (and do sometimes) use the latter in my own code, there's a good argument for the former in building a teaching resource.

Answer (score 0):

First, pass the relational AND operators into `bc` to get rid of some punctuation (also only invokes `bc` once):

```
if (( $(echo "$c1 < 0 && $c2 < 0 && $c3 < 0" | bc -l) == 1 ))
then
    >&2 echo -e "   ++ Constraints OK"
else
    >&2 echo -e "   ++ Constraints WRONG"
fi
```

Although if it were me, I would create a shell function returning a "true" exit status if bc evaluates the result of an expression to non-zero. Then you can hide most of the ugly punctuation in one place separated from your main logic:

```
function bc_true() {
    (( $(echo "$@" | bc -l) != 0 ))
}
```

And write a (IMO) cleaner shell expression:

```
if bc_true "$c1 < 0 && $c2 < 0 && $c3 < 0"
then
    ...
```

Comment: `bc -l <<<"$*"` is more efficient than `echo "$@" | bc -l` -- on real-world systems, creation and removal of the temporary file created by the heredoc is cheaper than the FIFO and extra subshell needed for the pipe from `echo`; doubly so in places where /tmp is on tmpfs.

Comment: BTW, consider either `foo() {` (POSIX sh syntax) or `function foo {` (legacy ksh syntax), rather than an amalgam that's compatible from neither of the sources from which it's derived; see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete.